# Repeating td tags inside a repeating tr tag in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-table, react-redux, repeat

Hi i've been trying to do the following in react but I get this error:

Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, address, long, lat, cityId, cityDistrict, phone, name, userId, city}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render method of `Comparison`.

this is my code:

```
       class Comparison extends Component {

 render() {
let comparedProperties = {
    id: [1001, 1002],
    address: ["abc", "def"]
};

let comparedItemsData = [];

for (var key in comparedProperties) {
    if (comparedProperties.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        let newTR = <tr key={Math.random()} className="compare-table-row">
            <td className="table-item-header">
                {key}
            </td>
            {comparedProperties[key].map((item) => {
                return <td key={Math.random()} className="table-item">{item}</td>;
            })}
        </tr>;

        comparedItemsData.push(newTR)
    }
}

return (
    <table className="compare-table">
        <tbody>
        {comparedItemsData}
        </tbody>
    </table>
  )
 }
   }

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
      ...state
      });
       const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
          actions: bindActionCreators(Actions, dispatch)
      });
      export default connect(
            mapStateToProps,
           mapDispatchToProps
        )(Comparison);
```

how can I repeat my td tags inside this repeating tr tag?
and only in this one loop over my comparedProperties object

**update answer:**

so I figuerd where the problem was but I expexted better error message from react the problem was that in my comparedProperties I had an object inside the array that caused the error

```
let comparedProperties = {"id":[101,102],"estateAgency":[{"id":1},{"id":2}]}
```

Comment: in that way, you are using just one TR, will you create more TR in a dynamic way?

Comment: what's your requirement? Or the end result you are expecting?

Comment: @RonitMukherjee this is my  data : `let comparedProperties = { id: [1001,1002], address: ["abc","def"], };` and the end result is displaying a table in render method

Comment: @JosephArriaza please read the code again, TRs are in a loop

Comment: I do not see any error when I run your code (just had to remove the comments). Can you work on your example a bit?: https://codesandbox.io/s/48yo4nvy7

Comment: also, looking at the error message: `Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, address, long, lat, cityId, cityDistrict, phone, name, userId, city})` it looks there is possibly a misplaced  `return` from the render method. Can you please check if you are returning from the render method at the expected place?

Comment: I have updated the code please see it again

Comment: I just checked with your code, and I don't see any issues

Answer (score 0):

If you will have multiples TRs and inside one you will have multiple TDs, you could use something like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';
import './style.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'React',
      trList: [
        {
          key: 'this is my tr',
          tdList: [
            {
              key: '1',
              name: 'this is my td 1'
            },
            {
              key: '2',
              name: 'this is my td 2'
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          key: 'this is my tr2',
          tdList: [
            {
              key: '3',
              name: 'this is my td 3'
            },
            {
              key: '4',
              name: 'this is my td 5'
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
  }

  getTds(tr) {
    const tdElements = [];
    for (var i=0;i<tr.tdList.length;i++) {
      tdElements.push(
        <td key={tr.tdList[i].key}>{tr.tdList[i].name}</td>
      );
    }
    return tdElements;
  }

  getTrs() {
    const elements = [];
    for (var i=0;i<this.state.trList.length;i++) {
      var htmlElement = <tr key={i}>{this.getTds(this.state.trList[i])}</tr>;
      elements.push(htmlElement);
    }
    return elements;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Hello name={this.state.name} />
        <p>
          Start editing to see some magic happen :)
          {this.getTrs()}
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: in this case I have to change my first data array structure, but I dont want to

Comment: this is my data : `let comparedProperties = {
         id: [1001,1002],
         address: ["abc","def"],
       };`

Answer (score 0):

```
    // Didn't test this; Hope this works for you.

    let comparedItemsData = [];

    for (var key in comparedProperties) {
      if (comparedProperties.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        let newTDs = [];
        newTDs.push(<td className="table-item-header"> {key} </td>);
        comparedProperties[key].map((item) => {
          newTDs.push(<td key={Math.random()} className="table-item">{item}</td>);
        });
      comparedItemsData.push(<tr key={Math.random()} className="compare-table-row">{newTDs}</tr>);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding of the requirement for which you are trying to write the code, I guess you can get some help from the below mentioned code:-

```
let comparedProperties = {
  id: [1001,1002],
  address: ["abc","def"]
};

let comparedItemsData = [];
let newTDs = [];
let th = <th key={Math.random()} className="compare-table-row">
  for (var key in comparedProperties) {
        if (comparedProperties.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        <td className="table-item-header">{key}</td>
    }
  }
</th>

comparedItemsData.push(th);

for (let i =0; i<comparedProperties.id.length;i++){
    let newTr = <tr key={'tr_'+i}>
    <td>{comparedProperties[id][i]}</td>
    <td>{comparedProperties[address][i]}</td>
  </tr>

  comparedItemsData.push(newTr);
}
```

***NOTE:- It's not the complete code. It's the only improvement of the bit of the code provided by you. For complete code post the complete code of the component or at least the render function.***

Comment: thanks but in comparedProperties[id][i] and I need "id" or "address" to be dynamically changed because comparedProperties is not always like this and can change dynamically elsewhere

Comment: @kouroshstst Thanks for updating the question. Can you provide som variations of comparedProperties so that I can understand it more. or feel free to connect with on Skype - happy_ronit

Comment: thanks, it can have different keys like this: `let comparedProperties = {"foundation": 100,"age":2}`

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'React',
      trList : {
        id: [101, 102],
        address: ['aaa', 'bbb'] 
      }
    };
  }

  getTds(tr) {
    const tdElements = [];
    for (var i=0;i<this.state.trList[tr].length;i++) {
      tdElements.push(
        <td key={tr+i}>{this.state.trList[tr][i]}</td>
      );
    }
    return tdElements;
  }

  getTrs() {
    const elements = [];
    for (var i=0;i<Object.keys(this.state.trList).length;i++) {
      var htmlElement = <tr key={i}>{this.getTds(Object.keys(this.state.trList)[i])}</tr>;
      elements.push(htmlElement);
    }
    return elements;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Hello name={this.state.name} />
        <p>
          Start editing to see some magic happen :)
          {this.getTrs()}
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: "Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child", this error was occurring because as per my assumption you are sending the item as an object.  send value into the dispatch.